# how to draw a shape by using canvas or css?

Tags: html, css, canvas

i'm looking for a way to create this shape with html(css) or canvas.

thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Please provide more info on this example, or your findings so far, otherwise we cannot help you

Comment: Please show your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
      context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
      startAngle = 1.2 * Math.PI,
      endAngle = 0.8 * Math.PI;

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(50, 70);
  context.lineTo(250, 70);
  context.arc(300, 100, 50, startAngle, endAngle, false);
  context.lineTo(50, 130);
  context.closePath();
  context.lineWidth = 5;
  context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
  context.stroke();
</script>
```

For detailed information have a look [here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/)